# Uploading photo from server to facebook

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook canvas application and I want to upload a file from my server to the user's wall.

Facebook says that a form should be created, this is what I did:

```
 <form action="https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=<%= @access_token %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="source" type="hidden" value="https://young-water-9853.herokuapp.com/images/1.jpg" />
        <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Upload photo" class="cupid-green" />
 </form>
```

This is the error I received:

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "(#324) Requires upload file",
>         "type": "OAuthException"
>      }
>   }

How can I make it work?

Solution:

This is the action I am using to post an image to the wall:

```
get '/post_photo' do 
  RestClient.post 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos', :source => open('http://i52.tinypic.com/313jaxd.jpg'), :access_token => ACCESS_TOKEN
  redirect '/'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source parameter needs to be a file object, not a url. If the user was uploading a file from their machine:

```
 <form action="https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=<%= @access_token %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="source" type="file" />
        <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Upload photo" class="cupid-green" />
 </form>
```

Or if you wanted the user to upload a predefined image, you'd take care of that server-side. The [rest_client](https://github.com/adamwiggins/rest-client) gem looks like an ideal solution for this:

```
require 'rest_client'
RestClient.post 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos', :source => File.new('/path/to/your/file'), :access_token => YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! because I want to use my own photo rest-client is the solution.  I manage to get this working from the irb, but it doesnt work from the server because I dont know what to write as the file's path. lets say I want to publish "images/1.jpg" from the public folder. What should I write as the path to this file?

Comment: If you're using RoR and the image is in `public/images` then you could get the path using `Rails.root.join('public', 'images', 'my_image.jpg')`

Comment: thanks, but I'm using Sinatra. Do you how can I do this in Sinatra?

Comment: `File.join('public', 'images', 'my_image.jpg')` should do it (not tested)

Comment: I solved it !  I put the images at image hosting server and then I got them by using 'open-uri'.